# Laravel / Mongodb - Get data from multiple collection

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am using [this](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package for my Laravel Application. I can get **single collection** data using this query:

```
$product = DB::connection( 'mongodb' )->collection( 'products_1' )->paginate( 5 );
```

Now, I have multiple collection for e.g:

> products_2, products_3, products_4 and so on...

**I want to get data from all the collection at once.**

Could you tell me is there any way I can get ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a `Product` model:

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $collection = 'products_1';
}
```

Then try to use `$unionWith` aggregation in `whereRaw` function:

```
$products = Product::whereRaw(function($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate([
        [
            '$unionWith' => [
                'coll' => 'products_2',
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$unionWith' => [
                'coll' => 'products_3',
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$unionWith' => [
                'coll' => 'products_4',
            ]
        ],
    ]);
})->paginate(5);
```

Ref:

- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/
- https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/2235

If not work, try `raw` with `toQuery`:

```
$products = Product::raw(function($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate([
        [
            '$unionWith' => [
                'coll' => 'products_2',
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$unionWith' => [
                'coll' => 'products_3',
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$unionWith' => [
                'coll' => 'products_4',
            ]
        ],
    ]);
})->toQuery()->paginate(5);
```

Ref: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1574

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It showing me: Call to undefined method MongoDB\\Driver\\Cursor::paginate()

Comment: @Shibbir Please try to use `whereRaw` instead. I have updated the answer.

Comment: ok. let me try this.

Comment: array_merge_recursive(): Argument #2 must be of type array, Closure given

Comment: any idea why its showing an error?

Comment: @Shibbir I'm not sure because I never used this package. Just updated the answer, hope that can help.

Comment: I tried **raw** with **all()** and it fetched all the data from the listed collections.

Answer (score -1):

I feel the best way to go about this is to define the model for the collection having in mind that relational db uses tables while non-relational db like mongo uses collections, ill suggest you define your mongo collection in a model class.

Just like a normal model, the MongoDB model class will know which collection to use based on the model name. For Products, the collection Products will be used.

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    protected $collection = 'products';
}
```